# If $M_1, M_2$ are two manifolds such that $M_1 \subset M_2$, show that $ \dim(M_1) \leq \dim(M_2)$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

We are given two manifolds $M_1 \subset M_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I need to prove that $\dim(M_1) \leq \dim(M_2)$. 
 This is part of calculus 4 course, and I haven't taken a course in topology yet, so the proof should be elementary. 
 I was able to show that if $k_1 = \dim(M_1), k_2 = \dim(M_2)$ then there exists an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{k_1}$, and another subset (which I don't think is necessarily open) $V \subset \mathbb{R}^{k_2}$, such that there exists an homeomorphism $T: U \to V$. Does that mean that $k_1 \leq k_2$ somehow?

Comment: I suspect you can use Brouwer's "invariance of domain".

Comment: It is enough to show that a ball in $\mathbf{R}^m$ cannot contain a homeomorphic copy of a ball in $\mathbf{R}^n$ if $n > m$. Try the case $m = 2$, $n = 3$.

Comment: @Alexey Why is it enough? we don't know if $V$ is open or not. Also, am I even in the right direction? Is it true that there can't be an open $U \subset R^k$ and another subset (maybe not open) $V \subset R^m$ such that there's an homeomorphism $T: U \to V$, if $k>m$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng I had no idea what is this, so I tried wikipedia. I'm not really sure if this can help solve the problem, since $V$ might not be open. However, In another exercise we were allowed to use the fact that $R^m$ is not homeorphic to $R^n$ for $n \neq m$, so I guess it can be used here too, and so are similar results.

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Comment: Because if $x$ is a (non-boundary) point of $M_1$, and you take a neigbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $M_2$, then $V = U\cap M_1$ is a neigbourhood of $x$ in $M_1$.

Comment: What is your definition of "manifold"?  There is an elementary proof if you are talking about _differentiable_ manifolds but for topological manifolds this is way beyond what you can hope to prove in calculus 4.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey I am talking about differential manifolds

Comment: @Eric Wofsey can you please share the proof?

Comment: This is still relevent. Can anyone help?

Comment: Let $\jmath: M_1\hookrightarrow M_2$ be the inclusion map and let $p\in M_1$. Then the linear map $d\jmath_p: T_pM_1\longrightarrow T_{p} M_2$ is injective, hence $\textrm{dim}(M_1)=\textrm{dim}(T_pM_1)\leq \textrm{dim}(T_pM_2)=\textrm{dim}(M_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\dim{M_1}=p$, $\dim{M_2}=q$. Suppose we have smooth atlases $ \{ (U_\alpha ,\phi_\alpha) \}_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}}$ and $ \{ (V_\beta, \phi_\beta \}_{\beta \in \mathcal{B}}$ mapping open sets in $M_1$ to open sets in $\mathbb{R}^p$, and those in $M_2$ to $\mathbb{R}^q$. Then, since $M_1$ is a submanifold of $M_2$ (since it is a subset with the structure of a manifold) we have an (injective) embedding given by an inclusion map $f:M_1 \rightarrow M_2$ so that, for any $x \in M_1$ $df_x: T_xM_1 \rightarrow T_{f(x)}M_2 = T_xM_2$ is injective. Thus note the linear map $d(\phi_\beta \circ f \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}):\mathbb{R}^p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^q$ is injective when restricted to appropriate open sets (since it is a compositions of injections).

The rank-nullity theorem then gives that $p = \dim{\mathbb{R}^p} = \dim \left(\ker{d(\phi_\beta \circ f \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}}\right) +$rank$( {d(\phi_\beta \circ f \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}}))$. But we know that the map is injective, so $ \dim \left(\ker{d(\phi_\beta \circ f \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}}\right) = 0$, i.e. $p = $ rank ($ {d(\phi_\beta \circ f \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}}))$. Finally, we note that the rank of a linear map is the dimension of its range, which in this case is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^q$. It follows that

$\dim M_1 = p = \dim{\mathbb{R}^p}$ = rank ($ {d(\phi_\beta \circ f \circ \phi_\alpha^{-1}})) \leq \dim{\mathbb{R}^q} = q = \dim M_2$.

Comment: @Omer does this answer your question?